# Angular 2 *ngFor not binding to String array

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

Angular 2 documentation seems to be correct. My String array located in app.component.ts does not seem to be recognized when called in app.html using the *ngFor="let hero of heroes"

Just trying to run through a tutorial all the help is greatly appreciated!

app.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Attribute
  } from 'angular2/core';
  import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common'



@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private newSearchTerm: string;
  private channels: String[];
  heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];

  constructor() {
    this.channels = [];
  }

  public newSubscription() {
    this.channels.push(this.newSearchTerm);
    this.newSearchTerm = '';
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="search-form">
    <form (ngSubmit)="newSubscription()">
      <input [(ngModel)]="newSearchTerm" placeholder="JavaScript" />
      <button>Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <ul id="channels-list">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      {{ hero }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working with rc3 release change, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yh1249aJGL5e2oHyonxd?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this:

heroes : String[]=  ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];